# how to integrate aadhaar verification API to java(spring mvc) web application from uidai site

Tags: java, spring-mvc, aadhaar

I'm doing a spring mvc web application, In that i want to integrate the aadhaar verication as a part in registration process of the web app. i've searched for so many solutions on the web for this, but I couldn't find any solution there. So,Any one? Pls.

Comment: Plz see this https://authportal.uidai.gov.in/developer Where they are provided maven projects for connecting aadhar api

Comment: thanx. But, I couldn't see any ways to integrate those things to my project. I want to verify the aadhaar number of the user with their DOB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not directly integrate with UIDAI and use their Aadhaar APIs.

To use Aadhaar APIs in your project you need to first get register with UIDAI to get the `license` for the same.

First, you will develop your application in their test environment.

Then there will be pre-production testing with UIDAI. Only after the successful testing, you can move to production.

More details at [UIDAI](https://authportal.uidai.gov.in/developer).

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other ways. Bcoz, I'm a student doing my project, So for that alone I need to integrate it. I don't want to hold a license for that.

Comment: @Pravinkumar It is sensitive data that UIDAI have. They will not allow anyone to directly fetch data from the Aadhaar API. Even to be able to hit their production API you need to purchase a Digital Signature Certificate which they integrate in their system to allow you to be able to fetch the data. It is really secure. And you need License from UIDAI obviously to do that.

Comment: Thank you agian for your clear explanation.@sandheep.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate the Aadhar card module in your application using [Offline E-kyc feature provided by UIDAI](https://resident.uidai.gov.in/offline-kyc).

**Steps**

1. First you need to download the XML file from Aadhar website by entering the aadhar card number and captcha followed by an OTP which will be sent on the registered mobile number.
   You also need to set up a passcode to secure the ZIP folder containing the XML file.
2. Next you need to write a business logic to parse the data from the XML after opening the XML file. You can also validate the file is you want to check for data tampering using the certificate provided and available on Aadhar website.

I will add the link to the github repository containing the sample code for parsing and validating the digital signature in Java.

Comment: Invalid link. DO you happen to have the latest link?

Comment: Yes, I will be sharing the link .